# Export sklearn model to pmml with variable names

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pmml

I am exporting a random forest model built in `scikit-learn` to a pmml object, but when I do so the variable names get changed to `x1`, `x2`, etc. Is there a way to retain the original variable names in the pmml file?

Below is an example with the `iris` dataset. In the `irismodel.pmml` file, the variables are listed as `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`, instead of `sepal.length`, `sepal.width`, `petal.length`, and `petal.width`.

```
#Load iris data and convert to pandas dataframe
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']], columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
iris.columns = [['sepal.length', 'sepal.width', 'petal.length', 'petal.width', 'target']]

#Split target and predictors
irisdata = iris.ix[:,0:4]
iristarget = iris.target

#Write out to pmml object
from sklearn2pmml import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

iris_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([('classifier', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10))])
iris_pipeline.fit(irisdata, iristarget)
sklearn2pmml(iris_pipeline, 'irismodel.pmml', with_repr=True)
```

Comment: Mine is showing correctly with python 3.6.

Comment: Can you try just using `iris_pipeline.fit(iris.data, iris.target)` where iris is the original (`iris=load_iris()`)

Comment: The problem isn't with iris, I'm just using that as an example. In reality I have other pandas dataframes I am building models off of.

Comment: Ok. Then @Aung said, in my system also the above code is correctly returning the feature names. I am using `sklearn2pmml v 0.20.3` and `scikit-learn v 0.18.1`. Can you check or update your versions?

Comment: Thanks, I had `scikit-learn v 0.17.1` and updating to `v 0.18.1` fixed the problem.